# W3C Validation: Ordered List element inside Label

Tags: html, xhtml, w3c-validation, xhtml-transitional

Given the fact that `<label>` and `<span>` are inline elements and `<ol>` is a block element, what is the proper way to nest an `<ol>` inside a span/label w/o using a script?

```css
input { vertical-align: top; }
label { display: block; }
label + label { margin-top: 1em; }
ol { padding:0; margin:0; }
```

```html
<label for="foo">
   <input id="foo" type="checkbox" />
   <span style="padding-left: 1em; display:inline-block;">
      <ol>
         <li>Boat</li>
         <li>Jet</li>
         <li>Chopper</li>
      </ol>
   </span>
</label>

<label for="bar">
   <input id="bar" type="checkbox" />
   <span style="padding-left: 1em; display:inline-block;">
      <ol>
         <li>Car</li>
         <li>Auto</li>
      </ol>
   </span>
</label>
```

The goal is to have an automated ordered list, which is not dependent on JavaScript, which is also considered W3C XHTML valid.

Comment: What  is your use case for this?

Comment: To properly nest a block element inside an inline element, one must first divide by 0.

Comment: I divided and divided, but all I could come up with are imaginary quarks.  Even tried making a div an inline, but that shouldn't be done. Use case.  I have a form with instructions, those instructions are formatted perfect using an ordered list.  I want a user to be able to click on them to check a checkbox; i don't want it to be JavaScript-based.  Go. :)

Comment: Seriously though, the use case is to have a clickable ordered list, assigned to an input.  This is used on a form and the surrounding `span` has more formatting to keep it consistent with the rest of the form document.  This is a legitimate and valid question.  I guess the only way would be to manually make a list using spans.  Though it also means that i'd have to go back through the css and add that class to every place a "ol" or "li" is used - a bunch of seemingly unnecessary work.

Comment: @vol7ron I still really don't understand your use case. Could you post an example somewhere?

Comment: @Michael: The example is posted above.  The only thing not included is the `<input name="foo" type="checkbox" />`, which is not needed.  I don't get what's hard to understand about nesting an ordered list inside a label.  As Stephen mentioned, `ol` is a block element, which I fully understood to begin with (hence: `Labels/Spans are inline. Ordered Lists are blocks. These are facts.`). ...

Comment: ... `label`, being an inline element, is not allowed to nest a block element.  This is a w3c-standards problem.  I can't imagine too many people would want to have an ordered list in a label, which is why this probably hasn't been a concern.

Comment: Why do you need a list of items as a label when the input is a single checkbox?

Comment: because it's the label.  It seems like you're trying to propose another solution, which I appreciate, but I was pretty specific in my question for a reason.  HTML is a basic language, but CSS seems to be changing drastically from version to version, I was hoping that there would be a legit way to include an ordered list, w/o manually mimicing the list, as in my answer.

Comment: Was this question ever solved? I...must confess that I'm at least as confused by the use-case for this question as is @Michael Mior.

Comment: @David Thomas: sweet name.  Yeah, I understand the confusion.  99% of the time this is a no-no, but it has to do with javascript-less form input and allowing users to click on the label to select the checkbox.  In this case the label is only an ordered (numbered) list.

Comment: The sole purpose is because the users of the form will be in the older computer-illiteratesque generation that expect to click on text next to an input and have it act as the button.  My problem right now is I have about 20 projects I'm working on, with probably another 30-40 on my things to do,  and haven't had time to come back to this one.

Comment: @DavidThomas remember this ancient question?  It's so old, but I was upset with the example and the phrasing -- I could tell I was in a rush (and overwhelmed) at the time.  Do you think this example better demonstrates using an ordered list as a label in order to trigger change of an input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* use an imagemap (`map`) to contain your list, but that may be abusing the `map` tag.

What I'm saying is something like the following:

```
<label for="foo" style="padding:1em;display:inline-block;">
  <map id="foolist">
       <ol>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
       </ol>
  </map>
</label>
<input name="foo" id="foo" type="checkbox" />
```

EDIT: W3C states that the [`map`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.6.1) attribute is block level:

> The MAP element content model allows
>   authors to combine the following:
>
> 1. One or more AREA elements.
>      These elements have no content but
>      specify the geometric regions of the
>      image map and the link associated with
>      each region. Note that user agents do
>      not generally render AREA elements.
>      Therefore, authors must provide
>      alternate text for each AREA with the
>      alt attribute (see below for
>      information on how to specify
>      alternate text).
> 2. **Block-level
>      content.** This content should include A
>      elements that specify the geometric
>      regions of the image map and the link
>      associated with each region. Note that
>      the user agent should render
>      block-level content of a MAP element.
>      Authors should use this method to
>      create more accessible documents.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would pass W3C specs, I'll have to check if `map` is one of the special block elements.  If so, I say abuse away.  I also have to check if it will continue to format it correctly.

Comment: It does validate, I have checked it with the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: I know in the coming weeks, I'm going to start working on the project that this was initially for.  I'll test it out then.  You may have a winner if it does validate and format correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one is answering I'll take a stab:

#### Manually create the list, using spans

---

```
   <label for="foo">
      <span style="padding:1em;display:inline-block;">
         <span class="ol">
            <br /><span class="li">1. 1</span>
            <br /><span class="li">2. 2</span>
            <br /><span class="li">3. 3</span>
         </span>
      </span>
   </label>
```

Every place you see an `ol{...}` or `li{...}` in the CSS, you'll have to insert the class; `ol,.ol{...}` and `li,.li{...}`.  Additionally, `.ol` would probably need to have `display:block;`

The line breaks could probably be replaced by a clear, but this is all off the top of my head, w/o testing.

Comment: Please don't name your classes `ol` and `li`. This just sounds confusing.

Comment: When they are to mimic an `ol` and `li`, this makes perfect sense.  This is the one and only time to name them that.

Comment: To me, when you're creating classes to mimic elements, it's a sign you're not doing something quite right.

Comment: @Michael: and any wise person would say that you're right, which is why this is a special case.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<title>foo</title>

<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
 span.c1 {padding:1em;display:inline-block;}
/*]]>*/
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ol>
<li><label for="foo"><span class="c1">1</span></label></li>
<li><label for="foo"><span class="c1">2</span></label></li>
<li><label for="foo"><span class="c1">3</span></label></li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me the question is still open.  One of the objectives is to avoid manually typing the numbers and avoid using scripts to compute them, thus relying on the browser and HTML-rendering support of the `OL`/`LI` constructs.